# str.startswith using Regex

Tags: regex, pandas, series

Can i understand why the str.startswith() is not dealing with Regex :

```
   col1
0  country
1  Country

i.e : df.col1.str.startswith('(C|c)ountry')
```

it returns all the values False :

```
   col1
0  False
1  False
```

Comment: are you sure `startswith` accepts string or regex as parameter?

Comment: `pandas.Series.str.startswith` does not accept regex.

Comment: I see! as i'am new to pandas, i was thinking that  we can use regex for startswith like i used it for str.replace(). thanks

Comment: Here's a non-regex alternative:  `df['col1'].str.startswith(('country', 'Country'))` (It accepts tuples for either-or)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Series.str.startswith` does not accept regex because it is intended to behave similarly to `str.startswith` in vanilla Python, which does not accept regex. The alternative is to use a regex match (as explained [in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern)):

```
df.col1.str.contains('^[Cc]ountry')
```

The character class `[Cc]` is probably a better way to match `C` or `c` than `(C|c)`, unless of course you need to capture which letter is used. In this case you can do `([Cc])`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifation @Mad Physicist this is useful

Comment: The link to the documentation does not jump to the relevant section: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern

Answer (score 9):

`Series.str.startswith` does not accept regexes. Use `Series.str.match` instead:

```
df.col1.str.match(r'(C|c)ountry', as_indexer=True)
```

Output:

```
0    True
1    True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This won't work if there is text following "country" since the whole expression must match. See my answer for something that is really equivalent to `startswith`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Not true, at least in v0.18.1. `Series.str.match` relies on `re.match`, which matches at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Also, match is now a deprecated function: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html#pandas.Series.str.match

Comment: @MadPhysicist Try yourself: `pd.Series(['countryasdf', 'Country']).str.match(r'(C|c)ountry', as_indexer=True)` gives `pd.Series([True, True])`.

Comment: Yes, with `as_indexer=True` this works. But still deprecated.

Comment: It may be deprecated, but it works. Before claiming something does not work, please make sure it really does not.

Comment: Without `as_indexer=True`, you get `pd.Series([('c',), ('C',)])`.

Comment: My mistake. I am using an earlier version of Pandas. You are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

`Series.str.startswith` can also receive a tuple like this:

```
df.col1.str.startswith(("Country","country"))
```

All elements from the tuple are now searched for. You can also read the tuple as an OR operator within `Series.str.startswith`.