# What is the syntax to select from pandas dataframe column, those elements which begin with particular alphabets using a single line of code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, if

```
df_table = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jason', 'Chris', 'Harry', 'Jacob', 'Arthur'], 'Salary':[7543,2387,6749,1472,8748]})
```

I want to select and show only the names starting with A and J.

I know I can select elements starting with A using:

```
df_table[(df_table['Name'].str.startswith('A'))]
```

and those starting with J using:

```
df_table[(df_table['Name'].str.startswith('J'))]
```

but how can I combine these two separate lines of code into a single code?

Comment: What you're looking for is `df_table[(df_table['Name'].str.startswith('A')) | (df_table['Name'].str.startswith('J'))]` . Check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for more info

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129020/str-startswith-using-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got the answer,thanks to @Xelvoz.
This should be the code:

```
df_table[(df_table['Name'].str.startswith('A'))|(df_table['Name'].str.startswith('J'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df_table[df_table['Name'].str[0].isin(['A','J'])]

df_table[df_table['Name'].str.contains('^[AJ]')]
```